# Syntax error with file-loader when upgrading to Webpack 3

Tags: webpack, webpack-file-loader

I am in process of upgrading to from Webpack 2 to 3 and I'm running into a problem with `file-loader@1.0.0-beta.1`. Here is the error I'm getting:

```
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| export default = __webpack_public_path__ + "foo.css"
```

(Omitted the full error details for brevity. This is the relevant part.)

Here is the Webpack config:

```
module: {
  rules: [{
    test: /\.scss$/,
    use: [{
      loader: 'file-loader',
      options: {
        name: '[name].css'
      }
    },
    'extract-loader',
    'css-loader',
    'sass-loader'
    fallback: 'style-loader/url'
  }
}
```

Before I was using `0.9.0` and there was no error. Looking at the difference between the two versions, I'm seeing that `0.9.0` returns a string that uses a CJS format instead of Harmony.

[0.9.0](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/file-loader/blob/v0.9.0/index.js#L51)

```
return "module.exports = " + publicPath + ";";
```

[1.0.0-beta.1](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/file-loader/blob/v1.0.0-beta.1/src/index.js#L78)

```
return `export default = ${publicPath};`;
```

I tried putting `babel-loader` after `file-loader` but that didn't fix the issue. I can use `0.9.0` and everything works fine however I would hate to be stuck at that version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in the `file-loader` beta. The correct syntax for the default export is (the `=` is not valid in the default export):

```
export default "/public/path/to/file";
```

This bug has been fixed, which will be in the next (beta) version. For now, you should use the stable version. Currently, the latest version is [`0.11.2`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/file-loader).

Comment: You're right. I completely missed that `=` but now looking at it, totally obvious. Thanks!